# Update picklist value to null with Sdk.Sync.Update does nothing

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Is it possible to update a record's attribute of picklist type with `null` by using  Sdk.Sync.Update? It's not working for me.

Here's what I do:

```
var detailsObj = updatedDetailsObj; // I get updatedDetailsObj from previous logic, not shown here
var operation = new Sdk.Entity("kcl_operation");
operation.setId(operationId, false); // I have operationId from previous logic, not shown here 
operation.addAttribute(new Sdk.String("op_updatedAccount", detailsObj.UpdatedAccount)); // works, get updated
operation.addAttribute(new Sdk.OptionSet("op_updatedExplanation", null)); // doesn't get updated
Sdk.Sync.update(operation);
```

After the completion of `Sdk.Sync.update`, the string field get updated, but the picklist field is left with its previous value, instead of `null`.
I also took a look inside the XML being sent inside Sdk.Sync.update, and indeed, it lacks the pair of `"op_updatedExplanation"` and `null`.

How can make it work?

**Added:**
I'm not doing it inside a form but inside a grid page, so that the user checks several records and I need to make the update on all of them.

Comment: the methods you are calling are customs, they are wrappers to the real SDK messages, you should ask to who wrote that methods

Comment: I don't mind not using them, I'll accept an answer that shows how can it be done in another way.

Comment: As Guido mentioned, you are using a custom library, which most probably does not support setting option set values to `null` properly. With only the snippet you are showing we can not help you to fix this.

Comment: What else would you like to know?

Answer (score 0):

standard CRM SDK code (assuming entity name and field name):

```
Entity operation = new Entity("kcl_operation");
operation.Id = operationId;
operation["op_updatedexplanation"] = null;
service.Update(operation);
```

where service is an IOrganizationService instance

Comment: I need it thorugh client side (i.e., with Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this snippet to set value as null.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("op_updatedexplanation").setValue(null);
```

This will just set the value in the form. You may have to save the form to see the value getting stored in database.

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
```

If the control is disabled - you have to set the submitmode attribute also.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("op_updatedexplanation").setSubmitMode("always");
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it: I'm not doing it inside a form but inside a grid page, so that the user checks several records and I make the update on all of them.

Comment: You have to explore & use these options whichever you are comfortable -
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309549(v=crm.7).aspx